How can I replicate Windows title bar features (Snap Layouts, tooltips) in a custom WPF title bar?
I'm working on a custom title bar for a WPF application in C#. My goal is to replicate the functionality of the default Windows title bar, specifically:
Windows 11 Snap Layouts: When hovering over the maximize/restore button, I want the Snap Layouts to appear, just like on a standard Windows 11 title bar.
Windows 10 tooltips: On Windows 10, if you hover over the minimize, maximize, or close buttons long enough, a tooltip (e.g., "Close") appears. I’d like to replicate that behavior as well.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
For the custom title bar, I’ve used WindowChrome to enable dragging and resizing functionality.
I’ve added my own minimize, maximize, and close buttons with Button controls.
However, I’m not sure how to:
Trigger the Windows 11 Snap Layout menu when hovering over the maximize/restore button.
Implement the yellow tooltips for the window control buttons that behave like the default system tooltips.
Are there APIs or built-in Windows functions that I can use to enable this functionality? Or do I need to completely recreate these features from scratch?
Pictures:



https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome?view=windowsdesktop-9.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
